# Is it possible to recursively traverse nested data classes \ convert them to a nested dictionary without expanding some types of dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a nested set of dataclasses that I want to convert to a dictionary
however, some classes should remain as a class, and not be converted to a dataclass
(the full structure is deeper and more complex)

in this example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict
@dataclass
class C:
    x: int = 1

@dataclass
class B:
    c: C = C()

@dataclass
class A:
    b: B = B()

asdict(A())
# returns
# {'b': {'c': {'x': 1}}}

# I want
custom_asdict(A())
# should return:
# {'b': {'c': C(x=1)}}
```

marking the class `C` as "do not expand" could be either as a parameter to `custom_asdict` or as a prameter to the `dataclass` decorator

Answer (score 1):

Although `dataclasses.asdict` allows for a "dict_factory" parameter, its use is limited, as it is only called for pairs of name/value for each field recursively, but "depth first": meaning all dataclass values are already serialized to a dict when the custom factory is called.

So, it is very hard to customize a "dict_factory" that would provide the needed behavior - on the other hand, it is possible to simply wrap "asdict" (or the inner function it calls) to do not serialize the classes you do not want.

That is way more straightforward, and, if needed, can be designed in a way to be turned "on or off" (for example, using unittest.mock.patch".)

Otherwise, just set for an attribute name to indicate the classes you don't want to serialize as dicts, and call the function bellow prior to calling `asdict()`. (This code checks for a `_dont_expand` attribute)

```
def patch():
    import dataclasses
    if getattr(dataclasses, "_patched", False):
        return
    original = dataclasses._asdict_inner
    def new_asdict_inner(obj, factory):
        if dataclasses._is_dataclass_instance(obj) and getattr(obj, "_dont_expand", False):
            return obj
        return original(obj, factory)
    dataclasses._asdict_inner = new_asdict_inner
    dataclasses._patched = True
```

I tested this in a Python shell with classes like yours and it works like a charm:

```
In [75]: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class C:
    ...:     _dont_expand = True
    ...:     x: int = 1
    ...: 

In [76]: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class B:
    ...:     c: C = dataclasses.field(default_factory=C)
    ...: 

In [77]: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class A:
    ...:     b: B = dataclasses.field(default_factory=B)
    ...: 

In [78]: a = A()

In [79]: a
Out[79]: A(b=B(c=C(x=1)))

In [80]: patch()

In [81]: dataclasses.asdict(a)
Out[81]: {'b': {'c': C(x=1)}}
```

(note: with this code you can set the `_dont_expand` attribute directly on instances you don't want to serialize: it will work just for those instances, while their class keep the normal behavior)